# How can i send images from server to my client?

Tags: java, spring, image, rest

I have been learning spring and to get the things together I am making an e-commerce application. I have used rest api to connect client and server. Now i need to send images to the client. My images are already stored in src/resources folder. What i need to know is that how do i send those images through rest api. so that i can use it in my client

I am very noob at this. I tried google and all i can find is examples of image files uploading to the server. I can't find a example of sending file from server to client through rest api. i've been stuck in this for past three day

Here is my rest controller:
now i need to know what should i do next so that i can send images

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CategoriesRestController {

// autowire customer service
@Autowired
private CategoriesService service;


//add mapping for GET all customer
@GetMapping("/categories")
public List<Categories> getCategories() {

    return service.getCategories();
}

// adding mapping for GET only one customer
@GetMapping("/categories/{categoryId}")
public Categories getCategory(@PathVariable int categoryId) {

    Categories categories = service.getCategory(categoryId);

    if(categories == null) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer id not found- "+ categoryId);
    }else {
    return categories;
    }
}

// adding mapping for POST/customer i.e. insert a customer
@PostMapping("/categories")
public Categories addCategories(@RequestBody Categories theCategories) { //@RequestBody will convert JSON to JAVA object

    // just to make things clear... always set id to 0 when inserting new object
    // so that it will be created instead of update
    theCategories.setId(0);
    service.saveCategories(theCategories);

    return theCategories;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking about the problem the wrong way. Instead of sending the *image* itself through the rest API, the HTML only needs the path to the image. You store the image in a directory, and you can pass the path to the image to your HTML. You could add a variable "imagePath" to Categories and the HTML could reference it in the  tag

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your images to base64:

```
byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePath));
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
```

and then send this property through your API. then in your client side you can use it like this:

```
<img src=json.encodedString />
```

Here `json` is an object which has been sent over API.

Before sending the `encodedString` you may appned at its beginning some things like below,  to make it easier to display in front-end:

```
"data:image/png;base64,"
```

To display a base64 image in front-end you should use some thing like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Read more:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-image-string

[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)